# cp works differently on a Mac

Tags: osx, windows, cp

I have the following code to copy an entire folder:

```
#!/bin/bash

B="H:\pdf2txt"

DST_DIR="H:\Test_Folder"

cp -r "$B" "$DST_DIR"
```

This works as expected on a windows machine but when I change it to this for my Mac:

```
#!/bin/bash

B="/Volumes/Mac_Storage/pdf2txt"

DST_DIR="/Volumes/Mac_Storage/Test_folder"

cp -r "$B" "$DST_DIR"
```

it copies the folder but then adds another copy within that one with the same content and then same again till the file path is too long for the mac to handle. folder structure like this:

```
Test_Folder
|   └── pdf2txt 
|       ├── test1.txt
|       ├── test2.txt
|       └── pdf2txt
|           ├── test1.txt
|           ├── test2.txt
|           └── pdf2txt
|               ├── test1.txt
|               ├── test2.txt
|               └── pdf2txt
|                   ├── test1.txt
|                   ├── test2.txt
|                   └── pdf2txt
|                       ├── test1.txt
|                       ├── test2.txt
|                       └── pdf2txt
|                           ├── test1.txt
|                           ├── test2.txt
|                           └── pdf2txt
```

etc etc..

Any idea why it works different from windows to Mac ?

Comment: Is this the entirety of the code? I can see some unused variables. I wonder if there is some kind of recursion? You can also debug with `echo`, e.g. repeat the `cp…` line with `echo cp…` above it, then see if the variables are as expected, and if it repeats unexpectedly.

Comment: @Sparhawk Sorry I was only using that one variable to test it, have edited post. It was part of a larger code but have deleted everything to eleminate problems but even with just the code you see above I am having the same re-occuring copy problem.

Comment: Is there a symlinks?

Comment: @roaima apologies typo, now corrected

Answer (score 8):

I think [telcoM's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/500383/98480) sniffs around the primary cause: It's likely to involve a symlink, just a different one.

Based on my experimentation, there's one set of circumstances that fits the bill:

- `Test_folder` is a symlink to `pdf2txt`, and
- the OP is using stock macOS `cp`, which has a BSD heritage

This sort of symlink defeats macOS `cp`'s cycle detection. (GNU `cp`, as would've been installed by [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/) or some other package manager, doesn't follow symlinks by default, even when copying recursively.)

Here's a demo, tested on macOS High Sierra:

```bash
$ ln -s pdf2txt Test_folder

$ ls -lAF Test_folder
lrwxr-xr-x 1 aho staff 7 Feb 13 20:13 Test_folder -> pdf2txt/

$ /bin/cp -r pdf2txt Test_folder
cp: Test_folder/pdf2txt/pdf2txt/pdf2txt/pdf2txt/pdf2txt/pdf2txt/pdf2txt/pdf2txt/pdf2txt/pdf2txt/pdf2txt/pdf2txt/pdf2txt/pdf2txt/pdf2txt/pdf2txt/pdf2txt/pdf2txt/pdf2txt/pdf2txt/pdf2txt/pdf2txt/pdf2txt/pdf2txt/pdf2txt/pdf2txt/pdf2txt/pdf2txt/pdf2txt/pdf2txt/pdf2txt/pdf2txt/pdf2txt/pdf2txt/pdf2txt/pdf2txt/pdf2txt/pdf2txt/pdf2txt/pdf2txt/pdf2txt/pdf2txt/pdf2txt/pdf2txt/pdf2txt/pdf2txt/pdf2txt/pdf2txt/pdf2txt/pdf2txt/pdf2txt/pdf2txt/pdf2txt/pdf2txt/pdf2txt/pdf2txt/pdf2txt/pdf2txt/pdf2txt/pdf2txt/pdf2txt/pdf2txt/pdf2txt/pdf2txt/pdf2txt/pdf2txt/pdf2txt/pdf2txt/pdf2txt/pdf2txt/pdf2txt/pdf2txt/pdf2txt/pdf2txt/pdf2txt/pdf2txt/pdf2txt/pdf2txt/pdf2txt/pdf2txt/pdf2txt/pdf2txt/pdf2txt/pdf2txt/pdf2txt/pdf2txt/pdf2txt/pdf2txt/pdf2txt/pdf2txt/pdf2txt/pdf2txt/pdf2txt/pdf2txt/pdf2txt/pdf2txt/pdf2txt/pdf2txt/pdf2txt/pdf2txt/pdf2txt/pdf2txt/pdf2txt/pdf2txt/pdf2txt/pdf2txt/pdf2txt/pdf2txt/pdf2txt/pdf2txt/pdf2txt/pdf2txt/pdf2txt/pdf2txt/pdf2txt/pdf2txt/pdf2txt/pdf2txt/pdf2txt/pdf2txt/pdf2txt/pdf2txt/pdf2txt/pdf2txt/pdf2txt/pdf2txt/pdf2txt: name too long (not copied)
cp: Test_folder/pdf2txt/pdf2txt/pdf2txt/pdf2txt/pdf2txt/pdf2txt/pdf2txt/pdf2txt/pdf2txt/pdf2txt/pdf2txt/pdf2txt/pdf2txt/pdf2txt/pdf2txt/pdf2txt/pdf2txt/pdf2txt/pdf2txt/pdf2txt/pdf2txt/pdf2txt/pdf2txt/pdf2txt/pdf2txt/pdf2txt/pdf2txt/pdf2txt/pdf2txt/pdf2txt/pdf2txt/pdf2txt/pdf2txt/pdf2txt/pdf2txt/pdf2txt/pdf2txt/pdf2txt/pdf2txt/pdf2txt/pdf2txt/pdf2txt/pdf2txt/pdf2txt/pdf2txt/pdf2txt/pdf2txt/pdf2txt/pdf2txt/pdf2txt/pdf2txt/pdf2txt/pdf2txt/pdf2txt/pdf2txt/pdf2txt/pdf2txt/pdf2txt/pdf2txt/pdf2txt/pdf2txt/pdf2txt/pdf2txt/pdf2txt/pdf2txt/pdf2txt/pdf2txt/pdf2txt/pdf2txt/pdf2txt/pdf2txt/pdf2txt/pdf2txt/pdf2txt/pdf2txt/pdf2txt/pdf2txt/pdf2txt/pdf2txt/pdf2txt/pdf2txt/pdf2txt/pdf2txt/pdf2txt/pdf2txt/pdf2txt/pdf2txt/pdf2txt/pdf2txt/pdf2txt/pdf2txt/pdf2txt/pdf2txt/pdf2txt/pdf2txt/pdf2txt/pdf2txt/pdf2txt/pdf2txt/pdf2txt/pdf2txt/pdf2txt/pdf2txt/pdf2txt/pdf2txt/pdf2txt/pdf2txt/pdf2txt/pdf2txt/pdf2txt/pdf2txt/pdf2txt/pdf2txt/pdf2txt/pdf2txt/pdf2txt/pdf2txt/pdf2txt/pdf2txt/pdf2txt/pdf2txt/pdf2txt/pdf2txt/pdf2txt/pdf2txt/pdf2txt/pdf2txt: name too long (not copied)

# Let's just look at the first 30 lines of a recursive ls
# (And yes, we're looking at pdf2txt)
$ ls -lRAF pdf2txt | head -n 30
pdf2txt:
total 0
drwxr-xr-x+ 5 aho staff 170 Feb 13 20:13 pdf2txt/
-rw-r--r--+ 1 aho staff   0 Feb 13 19:43 test1.txt
-rw-r--r--+ 1 aho staff   0 Feb 13 19:43 test2.txt

pdf2txt/pdf2txt:
total 0
drwxr-xr-x+ 3 aho staff 102 Feb 13 20:13 pdf2txt/
-rw-r--r--+ 1 aho staff   0 Feb 13 20:13 test1.txt
-rw-r--r--+ 1 aho staff   0 Feb 13 20:13 test2.txt

pdf2txt/pdf2txt/pdf2txt:
total 0
drwxr-xr-x+ 3 aho staff 102 Feb 13 20:13 pdf2txt/

pdf2txt/pdf2txt/pdf2txt/pdf2txt:
total 0
drwxr-xr-x+ 3 aho staff 102 Feb 13 20:13 pdf2txt/

pdf2txt/pdf2txt/pdf2txt/pdf2txt/pdf2txt:
total 0
drwxr-xr-x+ 3 aho staff 102 Feb 13 20:13 pdf2txt/

pdf2txt/pdf2txt/pdf2txt/pdf2txt/pdf2txt/pdf2txt:
total 0
drwxr-xr-x+ 3 aho staff 102 Feb 13 20:13 pdf2txt/

pdf2txt/pdf2txt/pdf2txt/pdf2txt/pdf2txt/pdf2txt/pdf2txt:
total 0
```

Comment: Thats basically what I am getting, it just keeps going and going and going till that 'name too long' error. I shall try the command and update the post tonight

Answer (score 6):

Is there a symbolic link `/Volumes/Mac_Storage/pdf2txt/pdf2txt` pointing to `.`?

Run `ls -l /Volumes/Mac_Storage/pdf2txt` to check.

If you see a line like this:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 madmiddle madmiddle 1 Feb 12 12:34 pdf2txt -> .
```

... then that is the cause.

The command to create such a link would be `ln -s . pdf2txt`, which might be fairly easy to happen accidentally as a result of a typo.

Comment: I'll have to read up on symbolic link is as I have no idea what that means. I shall run it tonight and get back to you.

Comment: Highly unlikely to be the case. macOS stock (BSD) `cp` stops the copy dead with the error `cp: pdf2txt/pdf2txt: directory causes a cycle`, which a Homebrew-installed (GNU) `cp` copies the directory correctly because it doesn't follow symlinks by default.

Answer (score 3):

I was really bored and i found this on the cp man page on my mbp runnin mojave:

COMPATIBILITY
     Historic versions of the cp utility had a -r option.  This implementation
     supports that option; however, its use is strongly discouraged, as it
     does not correctly copy special files, symbolic links, or fifo's.

So yeah, cp -r will not work properly on macOS